# How to fill in a string "hangman style"?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm writing a simple hangman game using Unity engine. The issue I'm having is this:
If random word is "one", then user guess as follows

Initial display : _ _ _

User types o : _ _ _ o _ _

User types n : _ _ _ o _ _ o n _

User types e : _ _ _ o _ _ o n _ o n e

The function I suspect is the problem looks like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < random.Length; i++) 
{
    if (guessBool [i])
        guessChar += random[i] + " ";
    else
        guessChar += "_ ";
}
GetComponent<TextMesh> ().text = guessChar;
```

How can I make it such that

Initial underscore : _ _ _

User types o : o _ _

User types n : o n _

User types e : o n e

Comment: Please post reasonably complete function... Side note: calling string "guessChar" may be confusing if you ever decide to read you code.

Comment: "Clear" (ie. create anew) the output string each time a new letter is guessed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reset your output before you modify it:

```
guessChar = string.Empty;
for (int i = 0; i < random.Length; i++) 
{
    if (guessBool [i])
        guessChar += random[i] + " ";
    else
        guessChar += "_ ";
}
GetComponent<TextMesh> ().text = guessChar;
```